# Odoo request via Java

Tags: java, xml, request, odoo, rpc

I do the requests with xml-rpc.

```
List singleTasks = Arrays.asList((Object[]) objClient.execute("execute_kw",
            Arrays.asList(db, uid, password, "project.task", "search_read",
                    Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList(
                            Arrays.asList("active", "=", true))),
                    new HashMap() {{
                        put("fields", Arrays.asList("display_name", "total_hours", "project_id", "user_id"));
                    }}
                )));
```

This unfortunately returns the following:

> [{project_id=[Ljava.lang.Object;@759ebb3d, user_id=[Ljava.lang.Object;@484b61fc, id=23, total_hours=11.0, display_name=TEST}]

I have no idea how to use or convert the Ljava.lang.Object, what does that mean and how do I get the real id's?

I think it has something to do with the type of the field, because its either a one2many, many2one or many2many field.

Comment: @Any update on this ?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same case, and I found this query. So I decided to implement the response.

Assuming that the relations are many2one, The query returns the related objects, so it must be taken separately, that is, you must perform the following query (for example for country):

```
final Map<String, Object> c = (Map<String, Object>)
((Object[])models.execute("execute_kw", Arrays.asList( db, uid, password,
                                "project.task", 
        "search_read",Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList("id","=", "id_project.task"))),new HashMap<String, Object>() {{
                                        put("fields", Arrays.asList(                                                
                                            "project_id"
                                        ));
                                    }}
                        )))[0];
```

//It takes the values
    Object[] as = (Object[])c.get("project_id");

Regards.